# Creating an object within another class C++

Tags: c++

I'm getting a strange runtime error that I simply cannot comprehend. 
I'm making an object of my class Circle, which has the following default constructor:

```
    Circle::Circle()
{
    this->radius = 0;
    this->center->setX(0);
    this->center->setY(0);
}
```

The variables that are being are initialized are:

```
private:
    double radius;
    Point *center;
};
```

When I try to make an object of the class circle, I get a runtime error. Now I only get this error when the Point objectis declared dynamically.
Is there anything wrong with my syntax? 
When I declare the Point in my Circle class like this instead:

```
Point center;
```

And initializes it like this instead:

```
Circle::Circle()
{
    this->radius = 0;
    this->center.setX(0);
    this->center.setY(0);
}
```

It works. 
Why do I get these errors when I create the object dynamically? Can I not use two "->" like in the first example?

This is my first post, I hope this is not a too stupid question. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors? And where did you create the `Point`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better use

```
Circle {
private:
    double radius;
    Point center; // <<<<<<< No pointer here
};
```

You don't need a pointer.

The problem with your current code is that no memory is allocated for your pointer variable. I'd also not recommend to do it (e.g. with `center = new Point()`). As mentioned, it's not necessary.

Also you don't need `this->` to access class members. Just use the member initializer list in your constructor:

```
Circle::Circle() : radius(0), center(0,0) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`center` is a pointer.  If you do not allocate any memory for it then you cannot access it as it does not point to a valid object.  To get a valid object we would use

```
Circle::Circle() : radius(0), center(new Point)
{
    center->setX(0);
    center->setY(0);
}
```

If `Point` has a constructor that takes `x` and `y` then you could even use

```
Circle::Circle() : radius(0), center(new Point(0, 0)) {}
```

But I do have to ask if you even need a pointer here.  If not then you could have

```
Circle::Circle() : radius(0),
{
    center.setX(0);
    center.setY(0);
}
// or
Circle::Circle() : radius(0), center(0, 0) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because `center` is a pointer that does not have memory allocated to it. Since no such object exists,

```
Circle::Circle()
{
    this->radius = 0;
    this->center = new Point; //call the appropriate Point constructor
    this->center->setX(0); //now these are valid
    this->center->setY(0);
}
```

also notice since `center` is actually a pointer in your implementaion, `center.setX(0)` is invalid, you should do `center->setX(0)` instead

Comment: They won't be valid. If you want to access a member of a pointer, you should use -> and not .

Comment: That was a small overlook I just caught it.